# Can't match string literal in regular expression

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match string literals with the possibility of internal escaped strings

What I've arrived at so far looks a little something like this:

```
def matchStringLiteral(input: String) = {
  val strLit = """(\"(\\.|[^"])*\")""".r
  input match {
    case strLit(s) => s"matched literal $s"
    case _ => "didn't match anything"
  }
}
```

Except when I try to use it like so:

```
val str = "\"welcome to \\\"GenericWebsiteName.com\\\"\""
println(matchStringLiteral(str))
```

it prints `"didn't match anything"` despite working fine on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rL0yP6/1)

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and more importantly *why*?

Comment: As a general troubleshooting technique for this kind of thing, you might try to match a shorter string against a simpler regex — reducing the length/complexity of both as necessary until you have _some_ kind of successful match. Then, incrementally add components back to the regex, one at a time, so at each step of the way, if it starts failing, you know exactly what change didn't work. Your search space for a solution will be smaller, and you'll be able to ask a more targeted question here on SO.

Comment: I don't see anything in posted regex. Can you please explain what are you trying to match?

Comment: so where's your working regex101??

Comment: It's on regex101 now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you define 2 capturing groups in the pattern (2 unescape parentheses in `("(\\.|[^"])*")`) and then just declare one single argument in the `case strLit(s)` - Scala expects *two* arguments for 2 captured values.

Thus, either define 2 arguments:

```
case strLit(s1, s2) => s"matched literal. Group 1: $s1\nGroup 2: $s2"
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0QAmqL)

Or - best - use [an unrolled version of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/xH8pR0/1) with a non-capturing group and without any capturing groups:

```
val strLit = """"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"""".r
...
case strLit() => s"matched literal $input"
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DsfAbE)

The unrolled version works much faster as it matches string literals in a linear way, without the excessive backtracking caused by the alternation in your regex.

Comment: I had no idea you could unroll your literals... Thanks!

Comment: :) Actually, [*unrolling-the-loop* technique](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) is very powerful. Whenever there is a way to unroll a regex based on alternation or a tempered greedy token, you should unroll the pattern.

Comment: question is, couldn't I just have done this `(\"(?:\\.|[^"])*\")`?

Comment: You could, though `(\"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*\")` is - I think - more correct, but why use a capturing group around the whole pattern at all? `match` requires a full string match, you can just use `$input` to display the matched string.

Comment: what would the downside be of using the shorter one? (ignoring the added capture group)

Comment: I have just written that unrolled pattern is more powerful, meaning the performance is much better with an unrolled pattern. It takes [14 steps for the unrolled version](https://regex101.com/r/xH8pR0/1) to fetch the match, and [it takes 113 steps](https://regex101.com/r/eZ5fM4/1) for the non-unrolled version to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
"""(\"(\\.|[^"])*\")""".r.findFirstMatchIn("\"welcome to \\\"GenericWebsiteName.com\\\"\"")
res3: Option[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = Some("welcome to \"GenericWebsiteName.com\"")
```

I think the problem is, that when you want to pattern match like this, your regex needs to have a single group (no nested groups allowed). When you use non-capturing group inside it works.

```
def matchStringLiteral(input: String) = {
  val strLit = """(\"(?:\\.|[^"])*\")""".r
  input match {
    case strLit(s) => s"matched literal $s"
    case _ => "didn't match anything"
  }
}

scala> matchStringLiteral(str)
res9: String = matched literal "welcome to \"GenericWebsiteName.com\""
```

Comment: yeah but the reason I'm using `match` is because I have about 40 other regexes that need to be matched, and the string literal one is the only one causing me a headache